# React : State and props on the same parameter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm a junior developer. 
I use Textfield of material ui, but i have a problem. I get the value by a property, and it works ! however i can't edit the textfield, so i would want to use the onChange parameter, this is my code :

```
<TextField ref="docLibelle" value={this.props.lastuploadfile.content}  onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange}
```

And my function :

```
_handleTextFieldChange = (e:any) => {
    this.setState({
        showReferenceIsRequired : false,
        libelDoc: e.target.value
    });
}
```

And I try that :

```
<TextField ref="docLibelle" value={this.state.libelDoc&& this.props.lastuploadfile.content}  onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange}
```

But it doesn't work .. How can i get the value by the property and edit also the textfield ?

Thank you for yours answers !

Comment: {this.state.libelDoc&& this.props.lastuploadfile.content} this will either return true or false. So, what is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is pretty simple. Since you want to be able to change the `textField` value and also initialize it with a value you can just setState with props in your componentDidMount method

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({libelDoc: this.props.lastuploadfile.content})
}
```

and use it like'

```
<TextField ref="docLibelle" value={this.state.libelDoc}  onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange}
```

Comment: Nice ! Thank you for your answer, it works ! It was simple, but i don't think about it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is, in value property you are using the `props` value and inside the `onChange` method updating the `state` value, because of that your `textfield` is **read only**.

**Solutions**:

**1.** Pass a `function` from parent component and `onChange` of `textfield` use that `function` to update the parent value, it will work, like this:

In Child component:

```
<TextField ref="docLibelle" value={this.props.lastuploadfile.content}  onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange}/>

_handleTextFieldChange = (e:any) => {
    this.setState({
        showReferenceIsRequired : false,
    });
    this.props.updateValue(e.target.value);
}
```

In Parent component:

```
updateValue(value){
   let = this.state.lastuploadfile;
   lastuploadfile.content = value;
   this.setState({lastuploadfile})
}
```

**2.** Store the `props` value in `state` variable and use that variable in value property of textfield.

Store the initial value of `textfield` in `state` variable:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {libelDoc: props.lastuploadfile.content}
}
```

Use that variable in `value` property in `textfield`:

```
<TextField ref="docLibelle" value={this.state.libelDoc}  onChange={this._handleTextFieldChange}
```

Update that `state` variable in `onChange` method:

```
_handleTextFieldChange = (event, value) => {
     this.setState({
         showReferenceIsRequired : false,
         libelDoc: value
     });        
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !